# GeoServer-Mviewer : point layers over surface layers

Tags: layers, overlay, order, z-index, mviewer

I am working on an interactive map designed under Mviewer package and using GeoServer to save symbols and layers. I have a specific issue on it: I managed to generate all layers correctly in my interactive map, but I would like to control their overlaying.

In fact, I would like to decide that point layers must always be over linear layers and zonal layers, as they recover the rest of the layers when you click on them. Is there a specific command I could use in, either GeoServer, or my HTML/XML files which control my files for Mviewer? I know there is the command z-index in HTML and if possible, apply it between all my different layers in the map.

Answer (score 1):

In the XML file of your mviewer map, you can add `toplayer` or `index` as parameter to your layers.

- **Toplayer**

`toplayer` is used to define a layer that will always be on top of your other layers.

```
   <layer 
       id="layerid"
       name="layername"
       type="wms"
       url="https:/yourgeoserver.com/ows?"
       visible="true"
       toplayer="true">
   </layer>
```

- **Index**

You can also use the `index` which indicates the position of your layer according to the `index` of the other layers:

```
   <layer 
       id="layerid1"
       name="layername1"
       type="wms"
       url="https:/yourgeoserver.com/ows?"
       visible="true"
       index="1">
   </layer>

   <layer 
       id="layerid2"
       name="layername2"
       type="wms"
       url="https:/yourgeoserver.com/ows?"
       visible="true"
       index="2">
   </layer>
```

You can find more information in [the documentation of mviewer](https://mviewerdoc.readthedocs.io/fr/latest/doc_tech/config_layers.html?highlight=index#zoom-sur-le-parametrage-de-gestion-de-l-ordre-d-affichage-des-couches).